# CodeIgniter Random PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object in ... mysqli_driver.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I find many posts that are close to this but none are the same. I have a heavily used CodeIgniter app that has maybe a couple dozen, totally random, fatal errors logged to the error log per day.

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

or

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

The member function is random. Row(), Query(), real_escape_string(), num_rows(), etc.

I added a log function to mysqli_driver.php that dumps a stack trace whenever it receives a non-object:

```
if(!is_object($this->conn_id))
// Dump stack
```

This tells me that the error is happening in random places in my app so I am assuming the problem is not in my code. That leaves my server configuration as the suspect. I can't find any smoking guns and I cannot reproduce the error.

I'm grasping at straws here. Can anyone offer ideas on what else I can do to track this down?

- CodeIgniter v3.x
- Apache/2.2.15
- CentOS 6
- MySQL 5.1.73

UPDATE: Here are the configs I use. Main DB connection:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'cfMaster',
    'password' => 'somemasterpw',
    'database' => 'cfMaster',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => FALSE
);
```

When connecting to an alternate DB:

```
// $userDb array contains all of the connection details.
$firmDb = array( "firm_id" => $userDb[0]->firm_id, 
"hostname" => $userDb[0]->hostname, 
"username" => $userDb[0]->username, 
"password" => $userDb[0]->password, 
"database" => $userDb[0]->database, 
"dbdriver" => "mysqli", 
"pconnect" => FALSE );
$this->db = $this->load->database($firmDb, TRUE, TRUE);
```

~35K connections per hour. ~20 failures per day. All of my database connections work fine literally 99.99% of the time. Finding that 0.01% failure is my issue.

Comment: This can either be related to your mysql server or your codeigniter database configuration. Can you show us your CI config for database? you may change hostname, username, and password if you wish.

Comment: This is a very large, heavily used system with multiple database configurations. It averages ~35K connections to the DB per hour. Since I only get 20 or so errors per day I am assuming my configs are OK. Adding my configs to the question now...

Comment: Did you found any reason behind this ? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Never found what was causing this. For other reasons though, we switched to PostgreSQL so the problem is gone. LOL

Answer (score 0):

"non-object" means that the variable ($db) doesn't refer to an object. Did you assign it to your database class (e.g., $db = new databaseClass();, or whatever the class you're using is named)?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$var = &new class(); with $var = new class();
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

try to load database on your method and try

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}
```